# windows store app(c++/cx) connecting from ti sensortag via ble no services found

Tags: windows-runtime, c++-cx, bluetooth-lowenergy

i'm working on Windows 8.1 Store app to recieve data from ti Sensortag bluetooth low energy device.

Scanning for Devices by DeviceInformation::FindAllAsync works properly:

```
void App1::MainPage::ScanButton_Click(Platform::Object^ sender,     
    Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    create_task(DeviceInformation::FindAllAsync(GattDeviceService::GetDeviceSelectorFromUuid(GattServiceUuids::GenericAttribute), nullptr))
        .then
        ([this](DeviceInformationCollection^ Geräteliste)
    {
        int Anzahl = Geräteliste->Size;
        auto Geräteliste_Iterator = Geräteliste->First();
        TestId = Geräteliste_Iterator->Current->Id;
        TestName = Geräteliste_Iterator->Current->Name;
    }
    );

    Geräte_Namen_Block->Text = TestName + TestId;
}
```

But when i try get characteristics or services for Device i just get back an empty Ivector:

```
 Guid DeviceInformationServiceUuid(0xf0002800, 0x0451, 0x4000, 0xB0,    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);
 Guid PeripheralPrivacyFlagCharacteristic(0xf0002a02, 0x0451, 0x4000, 0xb0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);

 void App1::MainPage::___Service_Button__Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
 {
create_task(GattDeviceService::FromIdAsync(TestId)).then([this](GattDeviceService^ Mein_Gerät)
{   
    TestId_vonDeviceService = Mein_Gerät->DeviceId; 
    //GattCharacteristic^ FirstCharacteristic = Mein_Gerät->GetCharacteristics(PeripheralPrivacyFlagCharacteristic)->GetAt(0);
    ServicesVector = Mein_Gerät->GetIncludedServices(DeviceInfoUuid);
    CharacteristicsVector = Mein_Gerät->GetCharacteristics(PeripheralPrivacyFlagCharacteristic);
    ServicesLength = ServicesVector->Size;
    CharacteristicsLength = CharacteristicsVector->Size;

});

}
```

I have added the Ids for the two services in the app manifest xml like this:

```
m2:Function Type="serviceId:f0002a29-0451-4000-b000-000000000000"/>  <!--Device Name-->

m2:Function Type="serviceId:f0002a01-0451-4000-b000-000000000000"/>  <!--Appearance-->
        <m2:Function Type="serviceId:f0002a02-0451-4000-b000-000000000000"/>  <!--Periperal Privacy Flag-->
```

I think this should be right. So now I don't know why?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you the easier way on using the SensorTag, my friend Juhana did a nice SDK for the SensorTag, and you can get it access to it from [his Blog](http://juhana.cloudapp.net/)

If you want to use your own code, in general the Pairing sometimes can be problematic. Thus try removing the pairing from Windows machine, and resetting the sensor. And then doing the re-pairing, and check that Bluetooth settings does indicate that it can connect.

Then I would add event handlers into your app for monitoring the connection to the device, as well as event handlers for value changed for characteristics. For these parts you could check a simplified example from [my blog](http://www.drjukka.com/blog/wordpress/?p=167).

Comment: Were you done with your answer? The last sentence isn't complete ... :)

Comment: :), I think I was already thinking something else when I finished that. Now edited the ending.